# How to get a variable in another js file in django?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am trying to use `Moovit` embedded services.

I want to put an origin and destination address automatically.
So, I've this function in a `JS` file that receives the origin address and open a new window.
I don't know how to get this data from `JS` in `HTML`.

```
function print_moovitmap(origin) {
    origin_ad = origin; //Origin_ad is global
    window.open('/new', '_blank');


}
```

I am working with `Django`. I have also `origin_ad` in a `form field` with an `Id` but I couldn't access to this form field in `HTML`. It gives me null.

```
    origin_address=forms.CharField(max_length=200,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'data_aux data','id':'origin_address'}))
```

In `HTML` (null):

```
console.log(document.getElementById('origin_address'));
```

And in `new.html`:

```
<div class="mv-wtp" id="mapa_moovit" data-to='' data-lang="es">

    <script>
        var m = document.getElementById('mapa_moovit');
        m.setAttribute("data-to", "Central Park");

        m.setAttribute("data-from", "Times Sq");
    </script>
    {% load static %}

    <script src="{% static 'moovit_script.js'%}"></script>

</div>
```

I need to set attribute `data-from` to `origin_ad` but I don't know how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you make sure `origin` is a window property (globally declared as a `window.origin = originValue`*  rather than `const` or `let`) you can access it in JavaScript in the opened window as

```
 const origin = window.opener.origin;
```

provided that when you open the window you specify `rel=opener` in the *windowfeatures* string:

```
 window.open('/new', '_blank', "rel=opener");
```

See also [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener), [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), [link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types)

Current browser support for accessing the opening window from a frame opened with `_BLANK` as the target does not seem to be explicitly provided. If you run into issues, you might try using a different target name, but repeatedly opening `'/new'` in a named window will always open it in the same window/tab. If this is preferable anyway, don't use `_BLANK`.

*Note that declaring opening window variables using `var` should be accessible from opened windows but feed back suggests that explicitly declaring them as window properties has wider browser support.